# MySQL - subquery or joining multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a little struggle with my mysql query. Maybe someone can help me.

Tables:

contacts:

```
|id|phone|first_name|last_name|email|company|
```

custom_values:

```
|id|c_id|custom_field_id|value|
```

The table custom_values got different custom_field_ids

```
id 4 = mobile
id 5 = fax
id 20 = 2nd phonenumber
```

The current query gives me all information from my contacts table.

```
concat(contacts.first_name, ' ', contacts.last_name, ' - ', contacts.company) as displayname,     contacts.phone, contacts.last_name, contacts.first_name, contacts.company, contacts.email
from contacts
```

Now I want to add the information from the custom_values table to the query above.
Is it possible to add 3 rows, that adds me mobile, fax and the 2nd phonenomber to every contact?

I tried with the next query, but that doesn´t work.

```
SELECT 
    concat(contacts.first_name, ' ', contacts.last_name, ' - ', contacts.company) as displayname, contacts.phone, contacts.last_name, contacts.first_name, contacts.company, contacts.email,custom_values.value as mobile 
from custom_values 
join contacts on custom_values.customized_id = contacts.id 
where custom_values.custom_field_id=4
```

thanks guys.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want additional *rows*, then your approach is fine.  However, I think you want additional *columns*, not additional *rows*.

One approach is multiple `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select concat(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name, ' - ', c.company) as displayname,
       c.phone, c.last_name, c.first_name, c.company, c.email, 
       cvm.value as mobile, 
       cvf.value as fax, 
       cvp2.value as second_phone 
from contacts c left join
     custom_values cvm
     on cvm.customized_id = c.id and
        cvm.custom_field_id = 4 left join
     custom_values cvf
     on cvf.customized_id = c.id and
        cvf.custom_field_id = 5 left join
     custom_values cvp2
     on cvp2.customized_id = c.id and
        cvp2.custom_field_id = 20;
```

Comment: yeah you are absolutly right Gordon, I want to add additional columns.
Query looks good, thanks so much